# Chaining command when running bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am just curious if I can chain a command after the execution of the bash script completes.

```
$ deploy-stg.sh <path to pem file>; notify-send "deployed"
```

Above example is just for demonstration. I want to save some time by adding notifications with all commands. So that team messages or further work is continued meanwhile not wasting any time starring at terminal. And for some reasons I can't include these commands in the script itself.

Comment: I am no sure what is the issue. The example you showed is perfectly ok. Is there a problem with testing it?

Comment: Thanks @marosg for reply. Indeed it worked. It was just my gut feeling as a newbie.

Comment: Note that chaining with `;` causes the notification to be displayed *unconditionally*. It's considered best practice to arrange for `deploy-stg.sh` to set an appropriate *exit status* (zero for success; non-zero otherwise) then you can chain with logical operators `&&` and/or `||` such that the notification reflects the exit status.

Comment: @Ravexina - it was an answer, I said it was perfectly ok to do so.

Comment: @marosg "I am no sure what is the issue.", "Is there a problem with testing it?" is a comment in my opinion. I've undeleted your answer. Please try to make it a little bit more like an answer. Thanks ;)

Comment: thanks @steeldriver but my most frequently used script is throwing error in case of success as well. so in that case I think `;` will do the job as well. But your point is legit for all other commands like long running migrations or backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you showed will work. Is there a problem when testing it?

One issue with using `;` to chain commands is that all of them always get executed. This might be a problem for your script, [as steeldriver mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255940/chaining-command-when-running-bash-script/1255943#comment2122130_1255940).

Instead of using `;` you may prefer to use `&&` in this case, to have the notification display only when the script ran successfully. Then, if the script encounters an error, like a missing file, a permission problem, or a command that doesn't exist or has the wrong syntax, the command chained after it with `&&` will not run.

However, depending on the script contents, you may need to adjust it to include [exit statuses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Exit-Status) (in Bash, zero is success, and anything else is an error), in case the script runs without any errors but still somehow fails to do what it was supposed to. You include these by writing `exit 1` `exit 2` and so on in the script, usually as part of a conditional. For example, here's a piece of code that checks whether the user running the script is root, and causes the script to exit with an error if they are not:

```bsh
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "Please run as root"
        exit 1
    else
        echo "You are root, continuing..."
fi
```